# Resampling with 'how=count' causing problems

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple pandas dataframe that has measurements at various times:

```
                     volume
t
2013-10-13 02:45:00      17
2013-10-13 05:40:00      38
2013-10-13 09:30:00      29
2013-10-13 11:40:00      25
2013-10-13 12:50:00      11
2013-10-13 15:00:00      17
2013-10-13 17:10:00      15
2013-10-13 18:20:00      12
2013-10-13 20:30:00      20
2013-10-14 03:45:00       9
2013-10-14 06:40:00      30
2013-10-14 09:40:00      43
2013-10-14 11:05:00      10
```

I'm doing some basic resampling and plotting, such as the daily total volume, which works fine:

```
df.resample('D',how='sum').head()   

            volume
t
2013-10-13     184
2013-10-14     209
2013-10-15     197
2013-10-16     309
2013-10-17     317
```

But for some reason when I try do the total number of entries per day, it returns a a multiindex series instead of a dataframe:

```
df.resample('D',how='count').head()

2013-10-13  volume     9
2013-10-14  volume     9
2013-10-15  volume     7
2013-10-16  volume     9
2013-10-17  volume    10
```

I can fix the data so it's easily plotted with a simple unstack call, i.e. `df.resample('D',how='count').unstack()`, but why does calling resample with `how='count'` have a different behavior than with `how='sum'`?

Comment: Did you find any explanation yet? This is particularly frustrating with multi-index

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't had time to research further, and no one has answered here, so no =(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does appear the `resample` and `count` leads to some odd behavior in terms of how the resulting dataframe is structured (Well, at least up to 0.13.1). See here for a slightly different but related context: [Count and Resampling with a mutli-ndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688355/how-can-i-count-a-resampled-multi-indexed-dataframe-in-pandas)

You can use the same strategy
 here:

```
>>> df
                     volume
date                       
2013-10-13 02:45:00      17
2013-10-13 05:40:00      38
2013-10-13 09:30:00      29
2013-10-13 11:40:00      25
2013-10-13 12:50:00      11
2013-10-13 15:00:00      17
2013-10-13 17:10:00      15
2013-10-13 18:20:00      12
2013-10-13 20:30:00      20
2013-10-14 03:45:00       9
2013-10-14 06:40:00      30
2013-10-14 09:40:00      43
2013-10-14 11:05:00      10
```

So here is your issue:

```
>>> df.resample('D',how='count')

2013-10-13  volume    9
2013-10-14  volume    4
```

You can fix the issue by specifying that `count` applies to the `volume` column with a dict in the `resample` call:

```
>>> df.resample('D',how={'volume':'count'})

            volume
date              
2013-10-13       9
2013-10-14       4
```

Comment: So I guess we can assume this is a bug. Nice workaround, though.

Comment: is there a simple way to achieve the same result with multiple columns?  For me this works but it is  a lot of typing with more columns:   df.resample('D',how={'volume':'count', 'open':'count', 'high':'count'})

Comment: `how` parameter is now deprecated, use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408082/modify-ohlc-resample-code-as-per-deprecated-warning