# resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'how'?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import os

files = os.listdir('D:\\Data\\200 Stocks 1 minute Data')
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Data\\200 Stocks 1 minute Data\\'+file)
    df['Date_time'] = df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']
    df['Date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_time'])
    ohlc_dict = {
        'open':'first',
        'high':'max',
        'low':'min',
        'close':'last',
        'volume':'sum'
        }
    df.set_index('Date_time',inplace=True)
    df.resample('3min',how=ohlc_dict)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows',2000)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    df.to_csv(file)
```

Here is my code. I have one minute data and I would like to convert it to 3 minutes. But I am getting this error. `Type error - resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'how'`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with assign back, because not inplace operation:

```
df = df.resample('3min').agg(ohlc_dict)
```

Comment: now it says, SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported

Comment: @Josepharasta - What is pandas version?

Comment: someone please help e

Comment: @Josepharasta - What is `print (df.columns)` ? there is one or more columns after `df.set_index('Date_time',inplace=True)` ?

Comment: the how parameter was deprecated with version 0.19 -- see this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408082/modify-ohlc-resample-code-as-per-deprecated-warning

Answer (score 1):

Few of the function from resample() has been deprecated.
use format like-  `data_frame.resample('arg value').aggregate_function()` For the above specific case use - `df.resample('3min').agg(ohlc_dict)`